# Static methods in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was looking through the React documentation and ran into the static method. I Was wondering in what sort of scenario it might be useful and couldn't think of any.

Is there a specific scenario in which static methods are useful when building components in React?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`defaultProps` and `propTypes` are static members of React components, they do not change for every instance. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

One example for static properties is to be able to track how many instances of an object were created (not React specific). Note that most of the time, static methods are a code smell if you are modifying state.

```
var Contacts = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    instanceCount: 0
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
     Contacts.instanceCount++
     return {};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div > Hello {
      this.props.name
    } < /div>);
  }
});
console.log(Contacts.instanceCount) // 0
ReactDOM.render( < Hello name = "World" / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
console.log(Contacts.instanceCount) // 1
```

Another example is a way to store constants.

```
var Contacts = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    MAX_VALUE:100
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div > Hello {
      this.props.name
    } < /div>);
  }
});

if (someValue > Contacts.MAX_VALUE) {

}
```

Comment: what is the difference in having a regular method and calling it within the component and having a static method?

Comment: React lets you use both and they behave the same. Typically, anything that doesn't change can be on the prototype or as property on the constructor so it use a single copy. The main difference is that you could override it per instance if you set it on the prototype

Comment: Do you have a specific example where a static method would be favourable over the other one?

Comment: It would be the same as in Java, static methods don't have access to `this`, and you don't need an instance. A reason for keeping it on the `Constructor` instead of `Constructor.prototype` is if you don't want instances to be able to override that value.

Comment: In the first code snippet on line 16 it should say "Contacts" as component name right? I know this post is about static methods and variables, but it could irritate React newbies