# writing function outside of a class in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I've seen code like this

```
function abc(){
  return 'abc'
}
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    static abc = abc;
    render() { return <h1>{this.abc}</h1>; }
}
```

where function `abc` is defined outside of a react class. I have no clue why the author did it that way, why can't just do it within the class?

Comment: Where have you seen this. can you give a reference?

Comment: @nikamanish https://egghead.io/lessons/react-write-compound-components

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are [ES6 static methods](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx) and are not exclusive to React. They are members of the component class and not of instances of the component. They are not used extensively in React, but they can be useful. It is even mentioned in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over):

> Sometimes it’s useful to define a static method on a React component.
>   For example, Relay containers expose a static method getFragment to
>   facilitate the composition of GraphQL fragments.

They can be used as common members of the Component, shared by all instances of it. To give you an idea, other [static members of a React class](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#class-properties) are `displayName` and `defaultProps`.

Also see [Static methods in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333996/static-methods-in-react). As you can see, there aren't many cases where you would use a static method.

Comment: Also see https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-a-good-usecase-for-the-es2015-static-methods especially the 3rd answer on that page

Comment: so you're exposing 'abc' function in above case?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by expose, but yeah, you can call it from any instance of `MyComponent`

Comment: But what's the reason to define function `abc()` outside the class? Why not define it as a static method inside the class?

Comment: @kost it's so like OP said. There is nothing different in what you said too

Comment: @Dane so your answer doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Comment: I don't know. What could possibly be better in defining the function outside? Maybe reuse it between classes

Answer (score 0):

For one thing declaring functions outside the class are easier to EXPORT. Which serves a great deal when testing your react application i.e. through jest.

Answer (score -3):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Contacts extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            Contact()
        );
    }
}
const Contact = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Contactssssss</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Contacts;
```

Comment: You should't write code-only answers. Please elaboreate and explain why your code is corect and important to question (will be more useful long term).

Comment: Explaining the function of your code, what it aims to fix and what exactly it does would improve your answer ten fold. This could be a fix to someones problems, however, the more novice and intermediate programmers might not be able to interpret what it is exactly that your code accomplishes. Therefore rendering it practically useless to anyone unable to glean an understanding from the bare code. Thank you for your contribution none the less.